# PHP auto commented out/redirecting to php script page in webserver

Tags: php, html

Currently I'm working with forms, trying to send a form submission to a text file. However, when I set the form `action` to my PHP script: `action="saveScript.php`, it redirects me to the PHP script's page in html.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/form.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="saveScript.php" id="twitterCardTest">
    <ul>
    <label for="fName">First Name: </label>
        <li><input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" size="5" maxlength="15"></li>
    <label for="lName">Last Name: </label>
        <li><input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" size="5" maxlength="15"></li>
    <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <li><input type="text" class="message" id="message" name="message" size="5" maxlength="140"></li>
    </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Info" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$file= fopen('test.txt', "a");
//retrieve existing file
$retrieve = file_get_contents($file);
$current = $_POST['fName'] . ' ' . $_POST['lName'] . "\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n";
//record information inputted by user
$write =  fwrite($file, $current);
$fileSize = filesize('test.txt');

$saveFile = file_put_contents( '/htdocs/', $current, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

if($file === FALSE) {
    die('Error writing file');
}
else if  ($file != FALSE) {
    echo "Information written to file";
}
else {
    die('no post data to process');
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Alternatively, I tried placing the PHP code into the html file after the body end tag. This resulted in the browser auto commenting the whole script out. I recently updated php using brew and I've configured my local web server to accommodate PHP. My question is how would I go about fixing this issue so my script is being read as php? In addition, why does this issue occur?

Comment: what do you mean, "php script's page in html"? You see the php source code in your browser?

Comment: It shows the PHP script on a separate page - the same way it would show if the php file was opened locally.

Comment: For starters you have four '}', but only three '{'

Comment: That has been fixed now. My apologies.

Comment: you're calling `fwrite()` without ever having fopen()'d the file in the first place. you're slurping the entire file into memory with file_get_contents(), adding your post data, then APPENDING that whole file, so every time you try to run this script, you'll be doubling the file's size, and then some.

Comment: `$location = '/Desktop';` you running this from your own machine/Windows?

Comment: you're also missing name attributes and this is a syntax error `<form form method="POST"` - Error reporting... that would've told you what's wrong. Your script is failing miserably, but you're not checking for errors.

Comment: How could I implement `fopen( )` beforehand? Would it be `$file = fopen('test.txt');`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am running it on a local web server on an iMac.

Comment: Forgive me for the errors in my script, I'm a novice in PHP coding.

Comment: like I said, you have missing name attributes for your inputs (don't depend on an ID alone) and a syntax error in your form tag. This `$location = '/Desktop';` with the file you wish to write, will result and interpreted as `Desktoptest.txt` rather than the intended  `Desktop/test.txt`, add a slash  `$location = '/Desktop/';`. However, I know nothing about Mac PHP folder structures. Whether or not that is the right path to use, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: you also don't have any `type="xxx"` for your inputs, so those stand to fail. I.e.: `type="text"`.

Comment: this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14999433/ and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Q: Does this work? `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` - ? If so, then we have success.

Comment: well then, your server isn't properly installed/configured. You need to find out why that is. Which webserver did you install; MAMP? Xampp? other? you will need to go over their documentation.

Comment: I'm using Mac's apache web server. I'll try and figure out why it is not properly configured.

Comment: @ThomasLittler You don't have a PHP in your machine. As a beginner, better go with MAMP.