# Form isnt working

Tags: php, html

Hi guys i created a table with form and `<select>` tags. Whem i press the submit button i want to save the data to the txt file. Then from txt file I want to load the save data. Please tell me guys what I am doing wrong :(

This is the original table with the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Stodola</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">Stodola</div>
<br>
<form method="post" action="jul.php" name="1">
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dátum</td>
        <td>Deň</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Hlavný čašník</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Čašník výpomoc</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Hlavný kuchár</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Pomocné kuchárky</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Prevádzkar</td>
        <td>Extra Čašník</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Extra kuchyňa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="1">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="2">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="3">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="4">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="5">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="6">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7/7/2017</td>
        <td>Piatok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="7">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="8">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="9">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="10">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="11">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="12">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="13">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14/7/2017</td>
        <td>Piatok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="14">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="15">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="16">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="17">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="18">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="19">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="20">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21/7/2017</td>
        <td>Piatok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="21">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>22/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="22">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>23/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="23">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>24/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="24">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>25/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="25">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>26/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="26">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="27">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>28/7/2017</td>
        <td>Piatok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="28">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>29/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="29">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="30">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>31/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <select name="31">
        <option>vyber</option>
        <option>Lenka</option>
        <option>Katka</option>
        <option>Maťo</option>
        <option>Lubo</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

This is jul.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Stodola</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">Stodola</div>
<br>
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dátum</td>
        <td>Deň</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Hlavný čašník</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Čašník výpomoc</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Hlavný kuchár</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Pomocné kuchárky</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Prevádzkar</td>
        <td>Extra Čašník</td>
        <td>Čas</td>
        <td>Extra kuchyňa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["1"]; ?>
        <br>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["2"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["3"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["4"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["5"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["6"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7/7/2017</td>
        <td>Piatok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
       <?php echo $_POST["7"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8/7/2017</td>
        <td>Sobota</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["8"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9/7/2017</td>
        <td>Nedeľa</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["9"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10/7/2017</td>
        <td>Pondelok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
       <?php echo $_POST["10"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/7/2017</td>
        <td>Utorok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["11"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/7/2017</td>
        <td>Streda</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["12"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13/7/2017</td>
        <td>Štvrtok</td>
        <td>10:00 - 22:00</td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $_POST["13"]; ?>
```

Comment: Where's your logic to save the text file? Also, why are you using a text file? Is it for documentation purposes or tracking or logging?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your HTML should look like:

```
<form action="**php file path goes here**" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

and your php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

**Note:** This answer is from [PHP write file from input to txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998961/php-write-file-from-input-to-txt) so please check before asking again.

Answer (score 0):

Can I add some details? Don't name the Submit button Submit. Use names like name="subSavetoFile" and add an id value too, like id="subSavetoFile". You may end up with multiple submit buttons and you'll want your JavaScript form check functions and your PHP logic to discern what you want to do and check.

Don't forget to add PHP data checking protection like intval(), floatval(), mysqli_real_escape_string(), filter_var() or have a list of approved values to winnow out potential attacks.